# How often does a device send a wifi probe request?

Tags: macos, request, wifi, probe, dbm

When a device has wifi enabled, it sends out a wifi probe request, containing your signal strength, SSID, and MAC adress. I was wondering, how often does a device send out this request?

I heard that when a device is connected to wifi, it will double the time each time that it sends out this request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend [this paper](https://frdgr.ch/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Freudiger15.pdf). It says that a device may do a probe request anywhere from 55 to 2000 times per hour.

On smartphones in my home network, I measured an interval of about 7 - 8 minutes when the phone is left untouched, but much shorter (a few seconds) if you're actually operating it.